# C++ const char* pointer assignment

Tags: c++, boost

I must have missed an obvious fact here -- haven't been programming C++ for a while. Why can't I print the c-style string after assigning it to a const char* variable? But if I try to print it directly without assigning it works fine:

```
#include "boost/lexical_cast.hpp"

using namespace std;
using boost::lexical_cast;

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    int aa=500;
    cout << lexical_cast<string>(aa).c_str() << endl;   // prints the string "500" fine

    const char* bb = lexical_cast<string>(aa).c_str();
    cout << bb << endl;                                 // prints nothing

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: [Prints 500!](http://ideone.com/A0tuqQ)

Comment: @MarkGarcia: It's undefined behavior.  So doing what you expect it to is a perfectly valid option for the implementation.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Of course. Just showing a real output. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C String returned by `c_str` is only usable while the `std::string` from which it was obtained exists.  Once that `std::string` is destroyed, the C String is gone too.  (At that point, attempting to use the C String yields undefined behavior.)

Other operations may also invalidate the C String.  In general, any operation that modifies the string will invalidate the pointer returned by `c_str`.

Comment: Ah yes I see now. This make sense, otherwise it'll be memleaks everywhere if c_str() returns a data placed on heap. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

`c_str` function is called on the result of the temporary `string` which is created from the `lexical_cast`. Since you don't save it, the string is destroyed at the end of that expression and thus accessing the pointer to the `c_str` of the string that has been destroyed is undefined behaviour.